# C# foreach question

Tags: c#, foreach

Does `C#` has something to offer for the following code *(in refactoring terms)*:

***I would like to be able to replace two foreach calls with a single call like `for every (x, x) possible pair`, can this be done?***

```
foreach (var image1 in sequence.Images)
{
    foreach (var image2 in sequence.Images)
    {
        if (image1 != image2)
        {
            metric.SetImageMetric(new ImagePair(image1, image2), 1.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a feeling this question can be answered by LINQ, but I know nothing about it.

Comment: I think you want a single call to perform the full Cartesian product. You aren't actually looking for the Image1 != Image2 test to be included in this single call, or are you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing quite as concise as Python's `itertools.product()`, but you can use Linq, as blogged by [Eric Lippert](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

I'd be inclined to break it up into two phases. First, a query to generate the desired sequence of pairs, and second, a foreach over the sequence:

```
var pairs = from image1 in sequence.Images
            from image2 in sequence.Images
            where image1 != image2
            select new ImagePair(image1, image2);

foreach(var pair in pairs)
    metric.SetImageMetric(pair, 1.0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is Zip method http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx

Comment: Zip method doesn't give all possible permutations between two lists.

Comment: Zip does not work here because @Yippie wants all possible pairing of images except when the two images are same.

Comment: Original post tagged this with zip which I think should have been product. I re-tagged.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var pair in sequence.Images
                    .Select(im1 => 
                              sequence.Images.Select(im2 => Tuple.Create(im1, im2))
                    .Where(pair => pair.Item1 != pair.Item2))
{
    metric.SetImageMetric(new ImagePair(pair.Item1, pair.Item2), 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I do agree. However the question asked for a single call. I upvoted the answer with the link to Eric Lippert's cartesian product implementation in LINQ, as that should be the easiest and prettiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Not efficient:

```
var permutations = sequence.Images.SelectMany (image1 => sequence.Images.Where (image2 => image1 != image2).Select(image2 => new ImagePair (image1, image2)));
```